# Use Node.js as an interpreter

Tags: c++, node.js

I would like to embed NodeJS in my application. The reason i would like to use NodeJS and not just the V8 directly, is because of the extensions that exist for NodeJS.
To do that i understand that i need to compile NodeJS with GYP. Got it. But how do i work with it? is there a static lib to link to? how to start it up? say i want to provide it with a V8 context, how do i pass it?

a bit at a loss here. hope for help.

Note - i want to activate nodejs from my C++ code, not the other way around. i understand extensions, this is not what i want.

Regards,
Gal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I got from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977901/how-to-build-nodejs-as-a-shared-library-from-source-code) the problem of immediate linking with node.js is still unsolved. Actually the workaround may be running it in a separated process like an ordinary command line application. You may save your script to file, pass it as cmdline argument, then obtain std output from the node.js executable.

Comment: been a while :) yeah, i agree. it's probably the best.

Comment: From the linked question: "Support for building as a shared library has been added in to node mainline"